# How to rename columns by position?

Tags: python, pandas

```
from pandas import DataFrame
df = DataFrame({
  'A' : [1, 2, 3]
  , 'B' : [3, 2, 1]
})
print(df.rename(columns={'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'}))
```

I know that I can rename columns like the above.

But sometimes, I just what to rename columns by position so that I don't have to specify the old names.

```
df.rename(columns=['a', 'b']))
df.rename(columns={0: 'a', 1: 'b'})
```

I tried the above. But none of them work. Could anybody show me a concise way to rename without specifying original names?

I looking for a way with minimal code. Ideal, this should and could have been supported by the current function interface of `rename()`. Using a for-loop or something to create a dictionary with the old column names could be a solution but not preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might assign directly to `pandas.DataFrame.columns` i.e.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3],'B':[3, 2, 1]})
df.columns = ["X","Y"]
print(df)
```

output

```
   X  Y
0  1  3
1  2  2
2  3  1
```

Comment: This will only work if you want to rename all of the columns.

Comment: I do need to rename all the columns. It sounds to be the most succinct solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
df.rename(columns={ df.columns[0]: 'a', df.columns[1]: 'b',}, inplace = True)
df
```

Prints:

```
    a   b
0   1   3
1   2   2
2   3   1
```

Answer (score 0):

With this method, you can rename whatever columns by position. It converts the index position (0, 1) into the column name and create the original mapping (`{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'}`)

```
c = {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}
m = dict(zip(df.columns[list(c.keys())], c.values()))
```

```
>>> m
{'A': 'a', 'B': 'b'}

>>> df.rename(columns=m)
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  2
2  3  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to rename them:

```
names = iter(['a', 'b'])

def renamer(col):
    return next(names)


df.rename(renamer, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

The advantage of this approach is that it is enough that you know the order of the columns to rename and `renamer` function does not even have to use its parameter.

Comment: Does it work for this case: `X, Y, Z, A, B` -> `X, Y, Z, a, b`

Comment: Doesn't. You would have to change the `renamer` a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear if the other solutions work in the presence of two or more columns with the same name.  Here's a function which does:

```
# rename df columns by position (as opposed to index)
# mapper is a dict where keys = ordinal column position and vals = new titles
# unclear that using the native df rename() function produces the correct results when renaming by position
def rename_df_cols_by_position(df, mapper):
    new_cols = [df.columns[i] if i not in mapper.keys() else mapper[i] for i in range(0, len(df.columns))]
    df.columns = new_cols
    return
```